# removing object from stage if not exist anymore in array

Tags: actionscript-3

i want to remove my object out of viewcontainer when i hit my object
hit works, removing out of array also, but i doesn't want to remove it from stage.
because index in the array is null. ok but how do you remove it then?

thanks

```
private function enemySpawnen():void
{
var enemyShip:SpaceShip = new SpaceShip();

Enemy[0] = enemyShip;
Enemy[1] = enemyShip;
}

private function renderEnemy(e:Event):void
{
if(Enemy[0] != null){
viewContainer.addChild(Enemy[0]);

Enemy[0].scaleX = 0.5;
Enemy[0].scaleY = 0.5;

Enemy[0].x = 600;
Enemy[0].y = 400;
}
else{
viewContainer.removeChild(Enemy[0]);==> problem
}
}

if(spaceBar){
var kogel:Kogel = new Kogel();
viewContainer.addChild(kogel);

kogel.scaleX = 0.08;
kogel.scaleY = 0.08;

kogel.x = heli.x + (heli.width/2) -225;
kogel.y = heli.y + (heli.height/2) + 30;

kogel.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, shoot);
function shoot(e:Event):void
{
kogel.x +=10;

try{
if(kogel.hitTestObject(Enemy[0])){
Enemy.splice(0,1);
}
}
catch(e:Error){

}
}
```

Comment: You else statment with your error will only ever run when the item is null, so it will always throw an error

Comment: You should removeChild on the line before you splice the array

Comment: Why are there two copies of this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13314520/my-object-doesnt-get-removed-in-array

Answer (score 0):

Your `else` statment that contains your error will only ever run when the item `Enemy[0]` is null, so it will **always** throw an error and is completely unnecessary (you might as well remove the whole else statement)

`Enemy[0]` is null because you've spliced it out your array.  What you need to do is have the line that is throwing the error, **before** you splice the array.

```
if(kogel.hitTestObject(Enemy[0])){
    viewContainer.removeChild(Enemy[0])
    Enemy.splice(0,1);
}
```

Also keep in mind, now that you've spliced the array, the item that used to be Enemy[1] is now referenced by Enemy[0] as your array indicies have shifted.