# my object doesn't get removed in array

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

the problem is when i shoot down my enemy he keeps re-spawning.
probably something i overlooked.

i can shoot it, it gets removed from stage but gets rerenderd because it still exist in my array.

thanks

```
private function enemySpawnen():void
    {           
        for(var i:uint = 0; i < hoeveelheidEnemy;i++){
            var enemyShip:SpaceShip = new SpaceShip();
            Enemy[i] = enemyShip;
        }
    }

private function renderEnemy(e:Event):void
    {           
        for(var i:uint = 0; i < hoeveelheidEnemy;i++){              
            if(Enemy[i] != null){
                viewContainer.addChild(Enemy[i]);

                Enemy[i].scaleX = 0.5;
                Enemy[i].scaleY = 0.5;

                Enemy[i].x = 500;
                Enemy[i].y = 400 - i*100;
        }
        }
    }

function shoot(e:Event):void
            {
                kogel.x +=10;

                try{
                    for(var i:uint = 0; i < hoeveelheidEnemy;i++){
                        if(kogel.hitTestObject(Enemy[i])){

                            Enemy.splice(i,0);==>problem when i set it to 1 or i then nothing happens
                            viewContainer.removeChild(Enemy[i]);
                            //trace("hit");
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch(e:Error){

                }
            }
```

My source code can be found here:  http://dl.dropbox.com/u/50815831/Nieuwe%20map.zip

Comment: you need to splice AFTER you removeChild. once you splice `i` no longer indicates the item you want.

Comment: what is `hoeveelheidEnemy`?  your for loop should be using `Enemy.length` instead of `hoeveelheidEnemy`

Comment: yes but i still got some problems
with i,1 if i destroy something on index 1 it removes also index2

Comment: hoeveelheidEnemy = numbers enemy = 5

Comment: you still have problems even after swapping the placement of your splice and removeChild lines?

Comment: yes, i have
changed splice (0,0) (i,0)(i,1) nothing that does it wright

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the child BEFORE you splice the array.  You also need to iterate backwards so your indices don't change mid loop.

Try changing your for loop to the following:

```
for(var i:uint = Enemy.length-1; i >= 0;i--){
    if(kogel.hitTestObject(Enemy[i])){
        viewContainer.removeChild(Enemy[i]);
        Enemy.splice(i,1); //do this after the above line, otherwise you're actually removing doing removeChild on the next item in the array
        kogel.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, shoot); //stop the frame handler
        break; //abandon the rest of this loop
    }
}
```

If `Kogel` is a bullet and you want it to only affect one enemy, then you need to break out of the loop once it destroys something.

As a tip for good practice. you should encapsulate the shoot function/enter frame handler into your Kogel class and just pass in the enemy array.

Something else I've noticed, your have your `renderEnemy` function run every frame, which is completely uneccessary, and causing undesired positioning.  Delete that function all together and put the code into your enemySpawned() method:

```
private function enemySpawnen():void
    {
        for(var i:uint = 0; i < hoeveelheidEnemy;i++){
            var enemyShip:SpaceShip = new SpaceShip();
            Enemy[i] = enemyShip;
            viewContainer.addChild(Enemy[i]);

                Enemy[i].scaleX = 0.5;
                Enemy[i].scaleY = 0.5;

                Enemy[i].x = 500;
                Enemy[i].y = 400 - i*100;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I can tell you that you HAVE to use splice(i,1)...that second argument says "remove 1 element starting at index i". splice(i,0) is "remove 0 elements starting at index i").

Comment: it still removes all the above indexes
index 1 will also remove index2

Comment: should something bin changed?
i replaced it, is see a performance increase but my original problem have you a solution for that?

Comment: is `kogel` a bullet? if so see my updated answer again. I don't understand your last comment.

Comment: sry it didn't change the awnser untill now

Comment: Performance for one (you'll have a memory leak otherwise), as it is you should remove the listener when your kogel is off the screen with no hope of hitting anything, otherwise it just stays in memory forever.  You should accept the answer if it worked out for you

Comment: only it re render the objects above each other.
how do you stop that?
they should remain on their location

Comment: That probably has to do with your `renderEnemy` method, which you have running every frame, though I'm not sure why.  just do the code from that function in your enemySpawned() method.